# Setting CSS class to href="/" in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to set the CSS class "selected" at my links in my sidebar. When I am at "home" e.g. root url / I'm having trouble setting this class. Since all URL's ends with /.

Here some relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var path = location.pathname.substring();
    $('nav#sitenavigation a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
});
```

How can I set "selected" to ONLY the a-tag containing: href="/" and not for example href="/events/" ?

Comment: seems like you're checking if it ends with / - what about if you check if it starts with /? or what if href="/" exactly?

Comment: What's in the href of that tag? What's the url on the homepage? If someone types in a slightly different url (like with/without the trailing / ) what shows up in location.pathname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *only* `=` ([attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)) instead of `$=` ([attribute ends-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var path = location.pathname.substring();
  $('nav#sitenavigation a[href="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('nav#sitenavigation a[href=/]').attr('class', 'selected');
```

That should do it - you're picking only links with an href of "/".  The only difference is the = vs $=.  To match your code exactly...

```
$('nav#sitenavigation a[href="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
```

The jQuery selectors page explains how all the different comparison operators work:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Final note - this code will strip any other classes on the link and replace them with selected.  To preserve any existing classes, use addClass() like so:

```
$('nav#sitenavigation a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('selected');
```